# video set to "true" in Skype video chat URI, but video is not enabled when call starts

Tags: android

I'm using the Skype API from their site: [skype apir/uri for video call](https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/reference#uriCallVideoExplicit)

which saiys the following URI "Calls other people on Skype, and automatically turns on the call originator’s video":

```
skype:skypeUserName?call&video=true
```

when I start the intent, it places the call successfully, but the video is NOT enabled, on either phone by default.

One suspicion I have is maybe everything after the question mark is getting stripped.
this is how I pass it in:

```
  static String skypeURI = "skype:stablesentryremote?call&video=true";

  public void initiateSkypeUri(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri) {

  // Create the Intent from our Skype URI
  Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
  }
```

But this could just be a skype bug.

[update] I read somewhere that this is a bug that started in the latest release of skype. So at this point I am looking for a work around.

Comment: Did you try 1 instead of true? Or yes or y?

Comment: Good Idea. I tried yes, didn't work. I found a different solution though before I was desperate enough to try to guess a URI haha.

Comment: Hello Siavash, Have you find any solution for this Skype Video calling issue ? We are still facing this Skype URIs video calling functionality. Please help us if you got any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've figured out that there seems to be a problem with video call in the newest versions of Skype for android and ios. Maybe the new apps treat video calls as a conference call even if it's a 1 to 1 call (which isn't supported as stated in the skype api/uri doc), I suggest you report this problem to MS through for example appstore (not sure if there's similar possibility to do so in google play?) and mention the same bug happens on android.

If you need something to work ASAP while waiting for MS to fix the bug I'll suggest a solution but it might not be worth the time you'll need to spend in order for a working implementation. But I'll leave that up to you to consider.

1. What you could do is send an message (or just do a regular call) to the remote sentry with an unique message ie: "videocall:requested *timestamp here*"
2. And then have a [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script running at a X seconds interval on your remote sentry, looking for the unique message above from point 1.
3. If the message is retrieved and identified as valid, then initiate a video call from your sentry towards the user.

There's some good skype functions here that might help you get started:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/96375-skype-functions/

Comment: Thank you am_. I already have reported the bug on a skype forum. Your other solution wouldn't work for me. both ends of my system are an android phone. and no matter which side initiates the call, video is disabled. now if there was an api to send an intent to skype to tell it to enable video, that would work. but so far I have not found such thing.

Comment: Ah, yeah - then I'd say you'r pretty much stuck with waiting for a new version of the app. Only thing I can think of is to try get access to SkypeKit. https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12322/what-is-skypekit

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing my own video call using the OpenTok libraries:

http://tokbox.com/opentok

after 2 days of research, I found their library to be the easiest to use. Once I downloded their example project, I had video call working in 30 minutes. Its free for 1on1 calls, and they charge bu the minute for conference calls. perfect for my case.